# 1999 Malibu Braking System

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, malibu

Just changed my whole braking system in the front. My brake line on the left blew a hole and I replaced it. Decided to change calipers and hoses. Bled the lines. When the engine is started the pedal goes to the floor,any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the reservoir? Did you bleed, refill, bleed, etc.?  Are there any leaks?

Answer (score 1):

You still have air in the system. 
Check the brake fluid level.

Then repeat the bleeding. Start with the right rear wheel.  Left rear.  Passenger front.  Driver's front.

Comment: I suspect you mean to say "check the brake fluid level." It's too small of a change to allow me to edit in the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Did you let the master cylinder run dry during the caliper replacement? If so, you'll have to bench bleed the M/C. You may also have to perform an ABS bleed procedure.

After you installed the new caliper and pads, did you press the pedal several times with the engine OFF to move the caliper piston into contact with the pad? If not, do that now.